# How can I register for IRCTC internationally (without a +91 mobile number)?

Tags: trains, indian-railways, irctc

When I try to register for the Indian Railway Catering and Tourism Corporation website (IRCTC) https://www.irctc.co.in/, it is mandatory to provide a +91 country code phone number.

How can I register for an account without a +91 phone number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since September '17, the IRCTC website has modified their sign up form. They have changed the **Mobile** field, to an **ISD-Mobile** field, and added the following message:

`International/NRI users with ISD code other than 91 have to pay Registration fees after successful registration i.e. on first login. Please note that the Registration fee for International/NRI users is Rs. 100 + GST.`

Even if you have previously managed to register with an international number, you will be prompted (at your next login) to pay this fee before you can continue using the account.

Comment: US$1.80 (£1.40 sterling, NZ$2.65) does not seem an enormous surcharge for foreign visitors.

Comment: Even so, a surcharge to just register on an e-ticketing platform is extremely rare, no matter the amount

Comment: 2022 , this feature was taken away!

Answer (score 16):

## If you have access to a mobile

Register an account with any mobile number, and then attempt to login. The login process provides mobile verification, which accepts international country codes.

These are the steps to take:

1. Complete the registration form using any phone number that meets the form's criteria (10 digits)
2. Receive the registration confirmation email. **Subject: IRCTC' s Online Rail Ticket Reservation User Registration Confirmation**
3. Attempt to login using your registered **user id** and **password** at https://www.irctc.co.in/eticketing/loginHome.jsf (you don't need to click Request OTP)
4. You will be prompted to verify your phone number (and email address if this has not been done yet)
5. Click **edit**, input a valid mobile number, and request an OTP to be sent. You will receive an SMS that says **OTP for mobile no verification of user id [your_id] is 12345**
6. Complete the OTP verification
7. Log out and log back in

## If you do not have access to a mobile

Complete step 1, then follow their instruction to contact **care@irctc.co.in** to recieve your OTP by email. They will ask you to provide a form of identification, such as passport.

Comment: Just to add to this answer that there is a list of other options on the Seat 61 website at https://www.seat61.com/India.htm#Buy-tickets-online some of which may also suit the OP.

Answer (score 0):

When selecting the country there are two options regarding india. One is India and another one is India(NRI). When we choose  only India the ISD number folder will block automatically and we can enter our mobile number by skipping ISD. When we choose India (NRI) or countries other than India  it will ask ISD also. Please check properly when selecting country whether its India or India(NRI).

Comment: never seen this