# How can I register in IRCTC without ISD field when residing in INDIA

Tags: irctc

As per the discussion in the following community thread, I have tried selecting INDIA, still, ISD option is available and not allowing me to register without entering valid ISD nos. Since this ISD field is a mandatory one, I have tried by providing my mobile nos. No luck.

**Thread:** [How can I register for IRCTC internationally (without a +91 mobile number)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100831/how-can-i-register-for-irctc-internationally-without-a-91-mobile-number)

https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19/vmatm:

> When selecting the country there are two options regarding india. One
>   is India and another one is India(NRI). When we choose only India the
>   ISD number folder will block automatically and we can enter our mobile
>   number by skipping ISD. When we choose India (NRI) or countries other
>   than India it will ask ISD also. Please check properly when selecting
>   country whether its India or India(NRI).

Could anyone help me with this?