# Registration IRCTC

Tags: trains, indian-railways, irctc

I have troubles with registration IRCTC.

I have tried to follow the steps suggested on [How can I register for IRCTC internationally (without a +91 mobile number)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100831/how-can-i-register-for-irctc-internationally-without-a-91-mobile-number), but I keep on getting the message "Please enter a valid Mobile number".

Comment: How many numbers do you give in into the form? Step 1 says it needs 10 digits

Comment: In the line "ISD-Mobile I entered 91 + 10 digits. In the line "Post Offive I have 10 digits.

Comment: Did you add a "+" before the 91 number?

Comment: If it still doesn't work, you can try Ixigo for train tickets booking.